# How to display cross hairs intersecting at the cursor position in chart area?

Tags: c#, charts, cursor, cursor-position

I have a line chart and I added cross-hair to show x and y axes values but there is a problem. The intersection of the X and Y axis cursor markers is not the same as the Mouse cursor location. I use the `MouseMove` event and as you see in picture my Mouse cursor(showed as red circle) is far away from intersection point.

How can I make the cross hairs intersect at the Mouse cursor position?

Here is my code;

```
private void chrtAcq_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{        
    lab_X_Axis.Location=new Point((e.X),90);
    lab_Y_Axis.Location=new Point(123, (e.Y));

    if (e.X<=125 || e.Y >=495|| e.Y<=90||e.X>=830)
    {
        lab_X_Axis.Visible = false;
        lab_Y_Axis.Visible = false;
        lab_X_Axis_Cur.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        lab_X_Axis.Visible = true;
        lab_Y_Axis.Visible = true;
        lab_X_Axis_Cur.Visible = true;
    }
    try
    {
        Double yValue=chrtAcq.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.PixelPositionToValue(e.Y);
        double xValue = chrtAcq.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.X);
        lab_X_Axis_Cur.Text = String.Concat(String.Concat(Math.Round(xValue, 5).ToString(), " , "), Math.Round(yValue, 5).ToString());
        lab_X_Axis_Cur.Location = new Point(750, e.Y);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {            
        throw;
    }
}
```

My display of chart area and cursor(red point) and x-y axes lines:

[image: My display of chart area and cursor(red point) and x-y axes lines]

Comment: What data type is `lab_X_Axis` and `lab_X_Axis_Cur` ?

Comment: What is `chrtAcq`? What are these:`lab_X_Axis`, `lab_X_Axis_Cur`? Where are they initiated and do those labels are child of the `chrtAcq`? My guess you need to transform coordinates to parent or something like that

Comment: lab_X_Axis and lab_Y_Axis are the lines that seen as plus,
chrtAcq is the name of my chart graph.
lab_X_Axis_Cur is the label that shows the value of x and y axes which is show the value as="36.5771 , 0.1" in the picture

Comment: _lab_X_Axis and lab_Y_Axis are the lines that seen as plus_ Huh? What lines do you mean? Where and how are they defined? Are they Labels??? Are they nested in the Chart or do they float above???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are working in `WinForms` and that you want to have the crossed line to match the cursor position and that the lines are very thin `Label`s (that's a lot of assumptions here)! Otherwise this answer might be utter nonsense ;)

The problem is that when you use the [MouseEventArgs.X](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.x(v=vs.110).aspx) property you get:

> the mouse coordinate values are relative to the coordinates of the control that raised the event. Some events related to drag-and-drop operations have associated mouse-coordinate values that are relative to the form origin or the screen origin.

Your offset in the X-Dimension is exactly the difference between the left border of the form and the left border of the chart. If you calculate this offset and add it to your coordinates it will work just fine:

```
int x_offset = chart1.Location.X;
int y_offset = chart1.Location.Y;

lab_X_Axis.Location = new Point((e.X+x_offset), 90);
lab_Y_Axis.Location = new Point(123, (e.Y+y_offset));
```

The result should look like this:

[image]

One last point: you can use String.Format to make your label of point values a little more readable:

```
lab_X_Axis_Cur.Text = String.Format("X: {0} Y: {1}",Math.Round(xValue, 5), Math.Round(yValue, 5));
```

Comment: The MousEMove arguments are in fact relative to the respective control, not the Form or the Screen.

Comment: Now it __might__ work; but the real problem is that the question is still quite unclear.. I would guess he maybe wants: `chrtAcq.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.SetCursorPixelPosition(e.Location, true);
            chrtAcq.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.SetCursorPixelPosition(e.Location, true);
            lbl.Location = new Point(e.X + 20, e.Y) ; lbl.Text = ...` to offset the Label we see by 20 pixels to the right. But who knows..? I would not offset the cursor axes, however!

Comment: the code works. I did not change it. Only included the information from the documentation, which also states that "Some events[...] have associated mouse-coordinate values that are relative to the form origin or the screen origin." I guess this applies also here.

Comment: _the code works_ oh well; maybe yes, maybe no, impossible to tell without knowing the real purpose of the OP..

Comment: @TaW true, I added the assumptions under which I operate.